# Pass array as a bindparameter to the datagrid in orocrm

Tags: php, symfony, datagrid, orocrm

I want to pass array in `DataGrid` as a parameter. Currently i am passing single value as:

**.twig file**

```
dataGrid.renderGrid(gridName, { products: '34'}, { cssClass: 'inner-grid' })
```

**datagrid.yml file**

```
bind_parameters:

            -   name: products
                default: null
                type: integer
```

But i want pass an array and bind that array with the `DataGrid`. 
I want the solution for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

datagrid.yml

```
source:
        type: orm
        query:
            select:
                - product.id
                - product.name
                - product.quoteQuantity
                - product.discount
                - product.customPrice

            from:
                - { table: %inventory_product.product.entity.class%, alias: product }
            where:
                and:
                    - product.id IN (:products)
        bind_parameters:
            -   name: products
```

.twig file

```
dataGrid.renderGrid(gridName, { products: productdata}, { cssClass: 'inner-grid' })
```

Just pass the array as a parameter and bind that with the datagrid file

Comment: In your twig file, how does `productdata` look like? What was the key value pair?